# change value in X random lines

Tags: bash

I have a file with three columns. The third column has a "1" in those lines that match a pattern in column 2 and the rest of lines has "0"s. In total, I have 636 lines with a "1" and now, I would like to keep only 64 of those lines with the "1", the other 582 should turn to "0" (even if they match the pattern in column 2).
For example, I have this:

```
ID1    Pattern    1
ID2    Notpattern    0
ID3    Notpattern    0
ID4    Pattern    1
```

and I would like something like this (the first line has turn to "0"):

```
ID1    Pattern    0
ID2    Notpattern    0
ID3    Notpattern    0
ID4    Pattern    1
```

Or, another way would be to find the pattern in the second column (which will be 636 lines) and add "1" in the third column only to 64 of them and the rest with "0".

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: the 582 lines you want to reset to `0`, they **must be** randomly picked or they can be any 582 lines?  E.g. is it ok to pick first line with `1` till the 582nd line with `1`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, they have to be randomly picked...

Answer (score 1):

This line will reset 582 lines' column3 from 1->0. The lines are **not** randomly picked.

```
awk '$3 && c<582{c++;$3=0}7' file
```

- You can move the `582` into a variable so that the one-liner can work with your dynamic requirement.
- If you want to keep the format (space, tabs) of your file, you need to take care of the `FS, OFS` variable.